# Intro page before index.php in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to set intro page before my `index.php` page in root directory. My web server is `Apache`. I put this code in my `htaccess` file :

```
DirectoryIndex i.html index.php
```

This is `i.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Personal Website</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="index.php">Enter</a>

</body>

</html>
```

But when I click on link , page still on `i.html` and I can't enter to `index.php`.

What is wrong?

Is there better method for this?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you set index as the welcome page as it usually is then have the link to the other page ?. I cant see a lot wrong with what you have done tbh.... hmm.

Try putting index.html or index.htm and leave the htacess stuff out, as the server will usually try to open the html file before the php file.

So using index.htm or index.html usually works fine for a welcome page as you don't need to configure anything usually, just place the file there and it will override index.php as the start page.

Comment: I use some CMS for my websites, I cant change index.php and must link intro to main page , this is reason for set intro page.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I have come across this before with Joomla. usually adding index.html works, as the server will get to that before it gets to index.php

Comment: Hmm that's strange, does it just go to index.php then , even when index.html is there ?. When you had the i.html there and clicked the enter link, was there an error of any kind ?.

Comment: When click on link it must go to index.php but it back to i.html. And there isn't any error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the following worked for me in a .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

FYI, the change to .htaccess does not require restarting Apache and should be immediate. You could try searching for DirectoryIndex in your .htaccess just to make sure it is not in there multiple times.

I know your question references i.html. I don't know if that makes a difference or not, but you could easily switch it to index.html to see.